# Why std::sort with polish collate is not working properly?

Tags: c++, sorting, polish

I have a task to sort vector in polish locale and what im trying to do is not working. Maybe this sorting is good but I don't understand it?

This is my approach

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  locale polish("pl_PL.UTF-8");
  wcout.imbue(polish);

  vector<wstring> v{
    L"Słoń", L"Bąk", L"Bocian",
    L"Ryś", L"Żyrafa", L"Lew",
    L"Żuk", L"Bóbr", L"Anakonda",
    L"Łoś", L"Bażant", L"Czapla"
  };

  cout << "Przed sortowaniem: ";
  for (const auto& s : v)
    wcout << s << " ";
  cout << endl;

  sort(v.begin(), v.end(), polish);

  cout << "Po sortowaniu: ";
  for (const auto& s : v)
    wcout << s << " ";
  cout << endl;
}
```

And what im getting is

```
Przed sortowaniem: Słoń Bąk Bocian Ryś Żyrafa Lew Żuk Bóbr Anakonda Łoś Bażant Czapla 
Po sortowaniu: Anakonda Bażant Bocian Bóbr Bąk Czapla Lew Ryś Słoń Łoś Żuk Żyrafa
```

But for example Łoś should be after L and M.
How can I get appropriate sort using only collate for polish location?

Comment: This lines up with [cppreference's example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/collate), so I guess the action item here would be to contact your C++ library's maintainer and convince them to change your C++ library localization logic...

Comment: The program has UB mixing wide and narrow output to the same stream. After fixing it, I cannot reproduce your results. The fixed program runs correctly on Windows with both clang/libc++ and msvc. On Linux, it runs correctly after setting a global UTF-8 locale (doesn't have to be Polish, can be C.UTF-8 for example; without it, the output is garbled, but the sort order is still correct according to the Polish collation order). Please show your compiler version and OS.

Comment: My compiler version is Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5) and my os is macOS 14.2.1 (23C71).

Comment: I tried to set a global locale for pl_PL.UTF-8 and it still give the same result.

Comment: I don't have an Apple computer. clang with libc++ on Linux works. So it's Apple collation that must be buggy. Or rather nonexistent, see https://blog.zhimingwang.org/macos-lc_collate-hunt